# Delete and find a node from binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, treenode

I am working on creating "find" and "delete" functions for a normal Binary Tree ( not search).  Below is the code for the find function:

```
bool Find_Node(FileItem * item, Node *current )  //function starts with root
{
    if (current->getNameItem() == item->getName() )  //getNameItem() retrieves the data name in node.
    {
        currentItem = current;   //I have set currentItem as an attribute ( pointer to a Node ) in the tree class. I created it to point to the node I want to find.
        return true;
    }
    Node* child [2];

    child[0] = current->getLeft();
    child[1] = current->getRight();

    bool res = false;

    for (int i = 0; res == false && i < 2 ; i++) 
    {   
        if(child[i] != NULL)
            res = Find_Node(item, child[i]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Is there any better way to find a node? and may someone please help me with the delete function.

Answer (score 2):

Add the base case for `NULL` to make the logic simple.

```
bool Find_Node(FileItem * item, Node *current )
{
    if(current == NULL ) return false;
    if (current->getNameItem() == item->getName() ) {
        currentItem = current;
        return true;
    }
    return Find_Node(current->getLeft()) || Find_Node(current->getRight());
}

void Delete_Node(Node*& current)
{
    if(current == NULL) return;
    Delete_Node(current->getRight());
    Delete_Node(current->getLeft());
    delete current;
    current = NULL;
}
```

If I can see the implementation of Node I could tell you how to implement the `swap` function you'll need

If the tree is really big This may cause a stackoverflow. But that issue can be resoloved by changing the solution from a recursive one to an iterative one.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. What about the delete function?

Comment: @MohamadOmarHindi I was confused for a second. I re-read the question and its clear now. Can you change the implementation of the `Node` class? Adding a swap method would really help with delete.

Comment: Yes I can. Sorry i didn't explain enough; In case the I node I want to delete has children, they must be deleted too, so no need for swap.

Comment: @MohamadOmarHindi awesome, then add a swap method for a node and you can use the delete function i made.

Comment: Yes but in my case i dont need the swap since all the nodes below the required node must be deleted too.

Comment: @MohamadOmarHindi thats easy then. Updated!

Comment: Im getting an error. I think its due to not setting the parent child to null ( parent of the main node we want to delete)

Comment: @MohamadOmarHindi What is the error. The code above set's each node to NULL in the last line. be sure the function takes a `Node*& current`.

Comment: I mean the parent of the first Node i want to delete. Suppose the target node to delete is "X", and "Y" is its parent. Okay the code deletes "X" and all its children, but we must set "Y" child pointer to NULL.

Comment: @MohamadOmarHindi to delete the node correctly we need `getRight()` and `getLeft()` to return a reference to the pointer. Not a copy of the pointer. so the signiture should be `node*& getRight()`. Or make the right and left public members.

Comment: Why your find function returns a bool instead a pointer to node (if a node is found) or NULL (if a node doesn't exist in the tree) ? In my opinion it is a better solution because you can call the function Find_Node() inside the delete function. Probably the Find_Node() is much more useful if return the pointer to node than just true or false. Let me know if you are agree with me or not. :)

Comment: I return a `bool` because that was part of OP's function signature and I didn't know if they need that or not. returning the `Node` or `NULL` is just as good I think.